# Interior point - what is it

Tags: analysis

I bet it is safe to assume that there are examples of open and closed sets here on stack exchange thus I will not dwell into that. Rather I would ask for the clarification of what an interior point is in the following (taken from Rudin's mathematical analysis book): "E is open if every point of E is an interior point of E"

Comment: Then can you tell us what is your interpretation of an interior point?

Comment: Probably means a point of the set about which one can place an open ball $B$ of radius $\varepsilon>0$ such that $ B \subset E $.

Answer (score 1):

In a topological (or metric spaace), $E$ is a neighborhood of $x\in E$ of there is some open set $U$ for which $x\in U \subseteq E$.

Specifically in a metric space there is some $r> 0$ for which $B_r(x)\subseteq E$.